# How can I create multiple rows from a single row based on a formula?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to create multiple rows from one in Pandas. For example, assuming I have this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Bob", "Mary", "Amy"], "Age": [22, 35, 58], "EarningsYearly": [100,200,50],})
df['Quarterly'] = df['EarningsYearly']/4
df

        Name Age  EarningsYearly    Quarterly
0       Bob  22   100               25.0
1       Mary 35   200               50.0
2       Amy  58   50                12.5
```

I can take early and turn it into quarterly but I actually want a new line for each so I can process each separately later. So my expected output is:

[image]

How can I do it? Also another similar question is can I generate the new lines within the command I used to create the Quarterely column? Or should I create it first then add new rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(4)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age  EarningsYearly  Quarterly
0    Bob   22             100       25.0
1    Bob   22             100       25.0
2    Bob   22             100       25.0
3    Bob   22             100       25.0
4   Mary   35             200       50.0
5   Mary   35             200       50.0
6   Mary   35             200       50.0
7   Mary   35             200       50.0
8    Amy   58              50       12.5
9    Amy   58              50       12.5
10   Amy   58              50       12.5
11   Amy   58              50       12.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`df.index.repeat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) + [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), as follows:

```
df_out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result**

```
print(df_out)

    Name  Age  EarningsYearly  Quarterly
0    Bob   22             100       25.0
1    Bob   22             100       25.0
2    Bob   22             100       25.0
3    Bob   22             100       25.0
4   Mary   35             200       50.0
5   Mary   35             200       50.0
6   Mary   35             200       50.0
7   Mary   35             200       50.0
8    Amy   58              50       12.5
9    Amy   58              50       12.5
10   Amy   58              50       12.5
11   Amy   58              50       12.5
```